# What are the reasons for multiple variants on how to write 茶 (tea)?

Tags: stroke-order, strokes

I'm learning on how to write basic Chinese characters and have some basic familiarity with some of the variants across Simplified and Traditional form. For some characters, such as 茶 (tea), I see a couple of variations with the bottom radical.

Can someone explain the differences or the rules between them? Specifically, why is the "wood" radical written differently: one with/without a hook (shu/shugou) and the last two strokes are connected/separate.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It might be a simplified 荼, which is not the same word as 茶

Answer (score 2):

Chinese calligraphy has 5 major styles (字體) - 篆書(大篆、小篆)、隸書、楷書、行書、草書(章、今草)等五種. In another word, a Chinese word has more than one way to write/express on paper.

**木** - 楷書
[image]

**Other styles:**

[image]